# how to integrate the alfersco with already existing rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I will try to integrate my application with alfersco for use some functionalities like documentation .. from alfersco to my rails application.

Answer (score 0):

you can use RESTapi and integrate own modules to alfersco

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.. there is any other  API to do that integration.